# CNAME records don't show on dns lookup services for use with mailchimp

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I'm trying to set up a mail service to handle communications with our customers.

Part of the setup is to create CNAME and TXT records pointing to the mail service to avoid being delivered to spam folders.

These are the settings required by mailchimp:

[image: Mailchip required DNS settings]

These records were set up more than 4 days ago and are displaying in my domain control panel but I can't 'authenticate' the domain with the mail service.

These are the CNAME records I have on my server:

[image]

As a check I looked up my domain (opale.co.uk) at MXToolbox and for some reason *none* of the CNAME records for my domain are showing up but the corresponding TXT records *are*.

Is there a server setting I'm missing that is preventing the cascade of the CNAME records? Or something else?

Comment: I bet there's something wrong with how you defined your `CNAME` entries. Without knowing any details of your DNS server, we cannot tell if there's any special handling of `CNAMEs`.

Comment: (If you don't mind) what were the names for which you were supposed to set `CNAME` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the answer is this:

Look at your `sip` CNAME, and compare it to the others.  Many online DNS control panels add your domain name implicitly to the records. In other words the CNAME demanded by Mailchimp should be defined in your DNS management GUI as `k1._domainkey`.

As it's written now, you've defined a CNAME record for `k1._domainkey.opale.co.uk.opale.co.uk`, which naturally no-one is looking for, and which makes the authentication check fail.

Comment: This is interesting. I've just set up a CNAME record for k1._domainkey so hopefully that will solve the problem. Assuming the sip record is set up correctly is there any reason why that wouldn't show up here? https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/opale.co.uk

Comment: It worked! I suspect it will take time to fully cascade but mailchimp is picking up the changes. Thanks very much.

Comment: Regarding the https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/opale.co.uk it's your domain apex and cannot have CNAME records. Meanwhile, the [k1._domainkey.opale.co.uk](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/k1._domainkey.opale.co.uk) shows ok at the same service. BTW, testing DNS with [DNS Propagation Checker](https://esajokinen.net/dns/)s is not a good idea as if there's any problems, they will be cached all over the world for TTL seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to point an MX record to a CNAME record? That could be troublesome, see RFC 2181, esp. section [10.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-10.3). If so, for a mail server with IP address of 10.10.10.10 instead of,

*example.org --MX--> mx.example.org --CNAME--> mx.example --A--> 10.10.10.10*

use,

*example.org --MX--> mx.example --A--> 10.10.10.10*

...but I'm only guessing at what might be the problem. Maybe expand your question with more detail of your current configuration to allow people to see what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

As per RFC you can't point an MX record to a CNAME, you could use the solution that Andrew suggested or, if the DNS server is managed by you, you can implement CNAME flattening.